# Running selenium test with nunit-console and mono

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ubuntu, selenium, nunit-console

When I try to run my test on my Ubuntu server with nunit-console, I get an error because he don't find the file.

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/var/www/test/SeleniumTest/SeleniumTest/bin\Debug/SeleniumTest.dll"

I think the reason is the backslash but this file is generated by visual studio.

Comment: I don't think the backslash is the problem. Are you sure the file is really there?

Comment: Yes the file is here when I hardcod the .sln to forwardslash it's okay and the same problem appear after for the next file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by backslash. Ubuntu can't recognize the path. You can try to run dll directly instead of solution file. It should be fine.